# "Запихнуть" класс в статическую библиотеку

Tags: c++, c++11, lib

есть вот такой класс:
namespace lib{
class.hpp:

```
template <class T>
 struct point
 {

    T x;

    T y;
    point(T X, T Y);
    point<T>& operator = (const point<T>& p);
};
}
```

вся реализация в файле class.cpp, но из кода выше вроде должно быть понятно что там.

так вот я компилирую его, ar'ом архивирую, но при линковке приложения выдаётся много `undefined reference to 'имя метода класса'`
и че делать? А то с кучей *.o файлов как то не удобно(да у меня ещё много подобных классов).

Comment: Что делать? Не класть реализацию шаблона в .cpp...

Comment: А зачем вообще нужен кастомный `operator=` тут? Компилятор сам сгенерирует.

Comment: шаблонные классы инстанцируются под каждый тип отдельно. Т.е. после компиляции point<int> и point<double> у вас будет ДВЕ реализации. И затем манглинг имен сделает ДВА разных экспортируемых символа